# Hubot - no arguments entered/parameters entered

Tags: javascript, node.js, hubot

I've just started using Hubot recently.

I'd like to know if a command is used, but no arguments have been entered.

```
robot.respond(/dothis (.*)/i, function(res) { ... };
```

This doesn't return anything if no arguments have been entered, even though it accepts 0 or more arguments.

```
robot.respond(/dothis/i, function(res) { ... };
```

This doesn't accept any arguments, but responds when called.

Not quite sure how to go about this, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd need a regular expression engine that handled positive look-behinds to do this in a straightforward way, and I don't think V8 (which is what Node is using under the hood) has that as of this writing.

There are lots of other workarounds, though. Here's one using `\b` which checks for a word-boundary:

```
  robot.respond(/dothis\b(.*)/i, function(res) { 
    if (res.match[1]) {
      res.send('We got the paramater: ' + res.match[1].trim());
    } else {
      res.send('Command called with no parameter.');
    }
  });
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still didn't detect on hubot when there were no arguments listed. It waits for the next command. Would there be any other workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

```
robot.respond(/dothis(.*)/i, function(res) { ... };
```

This works, that space makes all the difference. It will now take an empty string as an argument.

Comment: This will also respond to `dothisfoo` which may not be what you want (or it may not make any difference at all--I don't know your specific use case after all).